# yajra datatables responsive out of table in mobile view

Tags: html, css, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

this problem I searched here and on google, but it has not been solved, I created a responsive datatable with Yajra, when a field contains only a few strings the datatable runs normally, also when in mobile view. but when the field contains a long string, the column in the datatable out the table.I hope someone can help me.
sorry for my language which is difficult to understand, thank you.

App\Http\Controller

```
    public function dataTable()
    {
    $data = SubjectMatter::query();
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('course', function (SubjectMatter $model) { // get name from table users
            return $model->course->name;
        })

        ->addColumn('teacher', function (SubjectMatter $model) { // get name from table users
            return $model->teacher->name;
        })

        ->addColumn('classroom', function (SubjectMatter $model) { // get name from table users
            return $model->classroom->name;
        })

        ->addColumn('status', function ($row) { //get status Teacher from table users active or inactive
            if ($row->status == 0) {
                return '<span class="badge mr-3 badge-pill badge-danger">InActive</span>';
            } else {
                return '<span class="badge mr-3 badge-pill badge-success">Active</span>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('action', function ($row) { //button edit and delete
            $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)"
             data-id="' . $row->id . '" data-original-title="Edit"
             id="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></i></a> |';

            $btn = $btn . ' <a href="javascript:void(0)"
            data-id="' . $row->id . '" data-original-title="Delete"
            id="deleteBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i></a>';

            return $btn;
        })
        ->addColumn('start', function ($row){
            return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->start)->format("d F Y");
        })

        ->addColumn('end', function ($row) { //button edit and delete
            if ($row->end == null) {
                $end = 'No end of materi';
            } else {
                $end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->end)->format("d F Y");
            }
            return $end;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action', 'course', 'teacher', 'classroom', 'status', 'start', 'end'])
        ->make(true);
    }
```

This View:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-sm mb-0 dt-responsive" style="width:100%;font-size=12px">
            <thead class="bg-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Teacher</th>
                    <th>Classroom</th>
                    <th>Information</th>
                    <th>Youtube</th>
                    <th>Download Link</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    <script>
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: true,
        ordering: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('jsonSubjectMatter') }}",
        lengthMenu: [
            [5, 10, 25],
            [5, 10, 25]
        ],
        columnDefs: [{
            "width": "5%",
            "targets": 0
        }, {
            "width": "50%",
            "targets": 5
        }, ],
        columns: [{
                data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                data: 'name',
                name: 'name',
            },
            {
                data: 'course',
                name: 'course',
            },
            {
                data: 'teacher',
                name: 'teacher',
            },
            {
                data: 'classroom',
                name: 'classroom',
            },
            {
                data: 'information',
                name: 'information',
            },
            {
                data: 'youtube',
                name: 'youtube',
            },
            {
                data: 'link',
                name: 'link',
            },
            {
                data: 'start',
                name: 'start',
            },
            {
                data: 'end',
                name: 'end',
            },
            {
                data: 'status',
                name: 'status',
            },
            {
                data: 'action',
                name: 'action',
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false
            },
        ]
    });
    </script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFZH5.png

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, read here on how to ask a good question! https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Instead of just pasting all your code into the paste bins, please post the relevant code here (and then you can still put a link to your pastebins - please remember to format them correctly!)

Comment: thank you, and sorry this first post for me

Comment: add this also "scrollX": "auto", in datatable function as like you write serverSide: true,